# Is self signed certificate generated in Sandbox environment available on Production too?

Tags: certificates

I have generated a self-signed certificate on Sandbox environment and based on that have a JWT token that would be sent to my API being called from Salesforce on some action. Now since I am using the public key for decrypting the JWT token in my  application to authorize the call from SF, I need to hard-code that public key in my api code.

This same api would be called on PROD env too. So my concern over here is that if I create a self-signed certificate in Sandbox env, will it be available on PROD as well?

Comment: No, not exactly.. I am creating JWT token based on the certificate generated in SF and I have created a new self-signed certificate in Sandbox.. Will that certificate be available in PROD too ?  Otherwise I will need to generate a separate certificate in Prod or change piece of code to use the key as specified in your link in PROD.

Comment: No changes in sandbox carry over to production, unless you put them in a change set.  You don't hard code anything here - you store your data in a protected custom metadata or custom setting to re-use in your code so you can use the code in different instances.

Comment: @Ashna Arora you can export it from whatever is your _master_ org - create it in Prod, export it and import it in Sandbox or vice versa. The referenced answer shows how this can be done.